# javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses; nested exception is: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 Relay access denied

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, starttls

I have received Exception on While try to Send mail in java application

> javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses; nested exception is: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 Relay access denied

example configuration of what i have applied in application.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.pepipost.com"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");        
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");                
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "516"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.pepipost.com");
```

Comment: In local machine email is working fine but in live server this kind of exception i received

Comment: See the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#norelay).  If that doesn't help, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).